# Cannot install NPAPI Flash Player plug-in in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, flash-player, adobe-connect

I'm having trouble installing NPAPI Flash Player plug-in into Google Chrome on Mac OS X.

- Macbook Pro Retina 2014
- OS X 10.10.5
- Google Chrome 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)

I followed https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/kb/google-chrome-browser-incompatibility.html exactly but at the end I still do not see a secondary NPAPI Flash plug-in showing up in my chrome://plugins view:

[image]

I needed this for using Adobe Connect in Chrome, but when I try to share my screen it still shows the warning

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm having trouble installing NPAPI Flash Player plug-in into Google Chrome 45

As of version 45 Chrome has permanently disabled support for NPAPI plugins (from September 1, 2015).

See below for instructions on what to do fix problems with Flash.

---

#### Plugin-based content doesn't work on Chrome

> Plugins previously allowed extra features to be added to browsers. Most of these features can now be included by website creators in a more secure way by default as part of HTML5. Chrome support for these plugins ended September 1, 2015.

---

#### Why NPAPI plugins don’t work now

> In the past, many plugins were developed using an old system called
>   NPAPI. Today fewer sites are using NPAPI plugins and they have often
>   caused security risks on websites.
>
> To make browsing with Chrome safer, faster, and more stable, we
>   stopped allowing NPAPI plugins on September 1, 2015.
>
> Plugins that use NPAPI, including Silverlight, Java, and Unity, won’t
>   work. If you want to use a website that uses an NPAPI plugin, you’ll
>   need to use a different web browser.

---

#### PPAPI plugins still work

> Plugins that use a newer, more secure system called Pepper API (PPAPI) still work. That includes plugins that come with Chrome, like Adobe Flash. PPAPI plugins that come with Chrome update when Chrome does, so there's no need to install anything extra.

---

#### Fix Flash problems

> If Flash isn't working, try these solutions to fix the problem:
>
> Step 1: Turn on PPAPI plugins.
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. In the address bar at the top, type `chrome://plugins` and press Enter.
> 3. Click Details.
> 4. Scroll down to "Adobe Flash Player."
> 5. Under "Type: PPAPI," click Enable.
>
> Step 2: Make sure Chrome is up-to-date. You get Adobe Flash player on
>   Chrome automatically, and it updates when Chrome does.
>
> Step 3: Update Adobe Flash Player manually.
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. In the address bar at the top, type
>      `chrome://components` and press Enter.
> 3. Under "pepper_flash," click
>      Check for update.
>
> Plugins that use NPAPI, including Silverlight, Java, and Unity, won’t
>   work.

Source [Plugin-based content doesn't work on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en)

Comment: It seems this just mean the latest Adobe Connect no longer works in the latest Google Chrome, on Mac at least.

Comment: @Computist Could be. I don't have a Mac or use Adobe Connect so I can't test it.